# Angularjs: How to make ui-select have only one way model biding?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ui-select, ngsanitize

With the angularjs navite select directive the model binding is only one way while in ui-select this seems to always be two way binding.

```
  <ui-select ng-model="uiSelected.animal">

    <ui-select-match>
            <span ng-bind="$select.selected.name"></span>
     </ui-select-match>

    <ui-select-choices repeat="animal in (animals | filter: $select.search) track by $index">
        <span ng-bind="animal.name"></span>
    </ui-select-choices>

</ui-select>
```

**Here's the plunker showcasing my problem:** https://plnkr.co/edit/FkZsFcMrTveWjXR5HNyT?p=preview

**My issue:**

How do I make ui-select to only have a one way biding with the model, so that when I alter the selected scope model it is not binded to the ui-select? If I rephrase: how do I make ui-select act like angular native select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have to add a $watch to the animal/car and save your selected object in a different $scope variable. I don't see another way, since uiSelected references on an object in animals array.

Use on-select event:

```
on-select="onSelectCallback($item, $model)"
```

Have a look at this plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/Zcb9xlPm6TW7DFk1sjAO?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I thought of this. But to be honest I feel like this is a bit of a dirty fix. Since my models can be dynamically extended in numbers it would be great if there was a tidier way of fixing this.

Comment: Sorry ccostel, but since you use a custom directive (ui-select), I fear it is not possible to change model binding. ui-select does bind the selected value directly to it's ng-model attribute. uiSelected.animal references on a item in the $scope.animals array. if the object inside the array changes, this will directly influence the uiSelected.animal, since it's only a reference, not a copy of the object.

Answer (score 3):

Use unidirectional binding with this,

```
{{::animal.name}}
```

Comment: Hmm I really like this simple approach. The problem is that my models still remain binded and I need to post them to an REST endpoint later. Is there a way to have this unidirectional binding not just for the view but for the model as well?

Comment: @ccostel Try isolating your scope value.. check this article http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-sticky-notes-pt-2-isolated-scope/